# Columnwise setting all values that meet a condition to zero

Tags: numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements, setvalue

I have an array that looks like this:

```
    M=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,9,2],[3,5,6],[8,1,3]])
```

```
> M = [[1,2,3],
>      [4,9,2],
>      [3,5,6],
>      [8,1,3]]
```

For each column I want to set the two smallest values to zero.

Thus I sort them in descending order (I know ascending would be faster)

```
    M1 = np.sort(M, axis=0)[::-1]
```

Then I want to use something like

```
    for column in range(M.shape[1]):
        for row in range(M.shape[0]):
            if M[row, column] < M1[1,column]:        
                M[row, column] = 0
```

and receive:

```
> M = [[0,0,0],
>      [4,9,0],
>      [0,5,6],
>      [8,0,3]]
```

How can I make this last part more efficient (for array or DataFrame)?

Comment: Is this `M1[1,...]`, or `M1[row,...]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hey, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask here, that you construct with:

```
M < M1[1,:]
```

we can thus set the elements for which this condition holds to `0` with:

```
M[M < M1[1,:]] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, @Willem Van Onsem. This was, what I was looking for. I just did not know how to mask "columnwise". But it seems to be fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
M[M< M1[1,:]]=0
```

Outputs:

```py
[[0 0 3]
 [4 9 0]
 [0 5 6]
 [8 0 3]]
```